# Struts2 Token error on page refresh

Tags: struts2, token, csrf

I am getting token error on page refresh in struts2 application. What i am doing, I submit a form on page abc(this page having multiple forms to post different data on same url) with token and data to xyz page where i am displaying record based on data. Whenever i refresh the xyz page i am getting token error and then page will redirect to token error page.

What should i do to over come this issue. my CSRFstack is below.

```
<interceptor-stack name="CSRFStack">  
    <interceptor-ref name="token">
       <param name="includeMethods">*</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="dataSourceCheck"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/> 
</interceptor-stack>
```

I have found the suggestion i should place token session interception above all interceptors and stack, but this is also not working.

What to do to avoid this problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get.

Comment: Now question is how to use it ?

Comment: Use `redirectAction` result type.